# Self cross-join in pig is disregarded

Tags: apache-pig, cross-join

If one have data like those:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);

DUMP A;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
```

And then a cross-join is done on A, A:

```
B = CROSS A, A;

DUMP B;
(1,2,3)
(4,2,1)
```

Why is second A optimized out from the query?

info: pig version 0.11

== UPDATE ==

If I sort A like:

```
C = ORDER A BY a1;
D = CROSS A, C;
```

It will give a correct cross-join.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have to load the data twice to achieve what you want.

i.e.

```
A1 = LOAD 'data' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
A2 = LOAD 'data' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
B = CROSS A1, A2;
```

Comment: It's because of type of map-reduce jobs that are spawned in the background: however you do the join, you'll need two separate inputs.

Answer (score 14):

davek is correct -- you cannot `CROSS` (or `JOIN`) a relation with itself.  If you wish to do this, you must create a copy of the data.  In this case, you can use another `LOAD` statement.  If you want to do this with a relation further down a pipeline, you'll need to duplicate it using `FOREACH`.

I have several macros that I use frequently and `IMPORT` by default in all of my Pig scripts in case I need them.  One is used for just this purpose:

```
DEFINE DUPLICATE(in) RETURNS out
{
        $out = FOREACH $in GENERATE *;
};
```

This will work for you wherever in your pipeline you need a duplicate:

```
A1 = LOAD 'data' AS (a1:int,a2:int,a3:int);
A2 = DUPLICATE(A1);
B = CROSS A1, A2;
```

Note that even though `A1` and `A2` are identical, you cannot assume that the records are in the same order.  But if you are doing a `CROSS` or `JOIN`, this probably doesn't matter.